# How to Parse this HTML with Web::Scraper?

Tags: html, perl, dom, web-scraping, scraper

I am trying to use [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper) to parse the following HTML:

```
<div>
<p><strong>TITLE1</strong>
<br>
DESCRIPTION1
</p>
<p><strong>TITLE2</strong>
<br>
DESCRIPTION2
</p>
<p><strong>TITLE3</strong>
<br>
DESCRIPTION3
</p>
</div>
```

into

```
      'test' => [
                  {
                    'name' => 'TITLE1',
                    'desc' => 'DESCRIPTION1 '
                  },
                  {
                    'name' => 'TITLE2',
                    'desc' => 'DESCRIPTION2 '
                  },
                  {
                    'name' => 'TITLE3',
                    'desc' => 'DESCRIPTION3 '
                  }
                ]
```

I have the following code but I don't have much luck. 'TEXT' when processing 'p' gives both the text and what is between "strong" for example

```
      'test' => [
                  {
                    'name' => 'TITLE1',
                    'desc' => 'TITLE1 DESCRIPTION1 '
                  }
                ]
```

plus its only the first item.

Here is my code.

```
use strict;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper;

my $html = q[<div>
            <p><strong>TITLE1</strong>
            <br>
            DESCRIPTION1
            </p>
            <p><strong>TITLE2</strong>
            <br>
            DESCRIPTION2
            </p>
            <p><strong>TITLE3</strong>
            <br>
            DESCRIPTION3
            </p>
           </div>
           ];

 my $test = scraper {
 process 'div', 'test[]' => scraper {
    process 'p strong', 'name' => 'TEXT';
    process 'p','desc' => 'TEXT';       
   };
 };

  my $res = $test->scrape(\$html);
  print Dumper($res);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two points in your code that need changing.

To get only the *DESCRIPTION*-text, use xpath. `//p/text()` will give you the text-nodes directly under any `p`, so the ones inside of the `strong` are not included.

To make all blocks of `p` show up in the array, and not only the first one, make the first instruction be on `div p`. That way it grabs all `p` inside of a `div` and not only the one `div`.

```
my $test = scraper {
    process 'div p', 'test[]' => scraper {
        process 'p strong',           'name' => 'TEXT';
        process '//p/text()', 'desc' => ['TEXT', sub { s/^\s+|\s+$//g } ];
    };
};
```

Output (with [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer)):

```
\ {
    test   [
        [0] {
            desc   "DESCRIPTION1",
            name   "TITLE1"
        },
        [1] {
            desc   "DESCRIPTION2",
            name   "TITLE2"
        },
        [2] {
            desc   "DESCRIPTION3",
            name   "TITLE3"
        }
    ]
}
```